# What happens if you die before your ten years are up?

Tags: supernatural

In the *Supernatural* universe burying your photo with some hoodoo items at a crossroads summons a demon, said demon <strike>offers you a deal</strike> normally offers you a deal.

> "You can have that thing you wanted, and in exchange for your soul in ten years.

What if you die early? Does your soul go to hell anyway? Do demons prefer a soul ripped from its mortal coil, or does it not matter to them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes it happens in one episode. Crowley gets furious with a demon who had made this kind of deal. He actually says:

> *This isn't Wall Street, this is Hell. We have a little something called integrity.*

[Link to YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nNAvGfh-Uvg)

If the human who did the deal dies before the deal time, the owner of the contract decides what to do; usually, they take the soul.

However the contract could also have a clause for such an eventuality.

Comment: Considering the show originally aired on the CW, I doubt Crowley really dropped the F-bomb.

Comment: i remember cos he take me out a laugh with that xD

Comment: add link to the quote :)

Comment: Re-edited quote for appropriateness and accuracy.  Please don't edit profanity back in, where the original quote does not contain it and even the original author of the answer has previously edited it out.

Answer (score 2):

The demons don't promise you'll live for 10 years, unless that's specifically part of the deal. But as can be seen in a recent episode, they strongly discourage their own from cheating and killing those with whom deals are made... it's considered bad for business.

Comment: I agree on the 10 years thing, but the idea stands. And there are other kinds of ways to die before your time is up.

Comment: Dying seems to be much the same, whether it's due to natural causes, murder or being ripped to shreds by hell hounds. Season 7, Episode 8 covers the case of participants in a crossroads deal being murdered prior to the end of the ten year period, and I would assume that dying of natural causes would have the same result - your soul would go to Hell.

Comment: @Pureferret Of course there are ways to die. You could commit suicide, or get shot trying to buy dope. But the demons won't try to cheat you out of the 10 years, for fear that it will mean others won't sell their souls once they hear about it.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist is correct - Crowley himself is basically saying that the soul still comes into possession of the demon who made the deal regardless of how or when they died.  Perhaps more from that episode could be added to the answer?

Answer (score 0):

They would be sent to Hell early if the demon holding their contract takes their soul. Most of the time that's the case.

But sometimes, however, if the deed the crossroads demon promised as part of the deal is not fulfilled and the owner of deal dies, then the soul would not be taken to Hell.

Comment: where is the source for this answer ?